# Best way to trigger alarm on log errors for AWS lambda that runs every 3 week

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an AWS lambda that runs every 3 weeks and I want to trigger a CloudWatch Alarm every time there is a line with "ERROR" in the logs. Based on the fact that the [maximum Alarm Evaluation Period is 1 day](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_limits.html) for a CloudWatch Metric Alarm, what is the best way to monitor these errors and trigger an alarm?

I was thinking of:

- creating a Log Filter (Metric)
- crating a CloudWath Metric Alarm with period = 1 day

but I'm not sure, log data are too rare. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking of:
>
> - creating a Log Filter (Metric)
> - crating a CloudWath Metric Alarm with    period = 1 day

Yes, that's exactly what you need to do. It will work just fine.

> but I'm not sure, log data are too rare.

This is not a problem. Every day the metric alarm will evaluate the logs, and then send you a message if there is an error in the logs. If the Lambda function didn't run that day, then there will be no logs for the Metric to evaluate, so it will do nothing (which is not a problem). I would even suggest changing it to evaluate the logs more often, like once an hour.

The maximum alarm evaluation period of 1 day just means you can't configure an alarm like this:

- Alarm if there are 2 error messages that occur within 72 hours of each other.

But you aren't trying to do that at all. You aren't trying to aggregate the number of alarms over a period of multiple days, you are simply wanting to know if there is an error message at all.

There is no such thing as a "logs too rare" problem here.

Comment: cool! And what about how to handle missing data points?

Comment: You have options for missing data points here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html#alarms-and-missing-data You would set it to "Not Breaching".  Although I don't think this is even an issue for a log based alarm. The metric count would just be 0 since there were no log messages with that string in that time.

Comment: if the metric is still 0 than handling no data points will be useless. Tx Mark.